# How to sum up a dataframe column based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have data about salaries where the columns are:

```
Index(['Id', 'EmployeeName', 'JobTitle', 'BasePay', 'OvertimePay', 'OtherPay',
   'Benefits', 'TotalPay', 'TotalPayBenefits', 'Year', 'Notes', 'Agency',
   'Status'],
  dtype='object')
```

where i created two extra columns to check whether their jobTitle has to do with police or fire fighter department

```
  def find_police(x):
    return "POLICE" in x
def find_fire(x):
    return 'FIRE' in x


# use apply to search for it in JobTitle
sf_sal["isPolice"] = sf_sal["JobTitle"].apply(find_police)
sf_sal["isFire"] = sf_sal["JobTitle"].apply(find_fire)

sf_sal[["JobTitle", "isPolice", "isFire"]]
```

So what i would like to do is compare the mean salaries of the police department and firefigher department, i get the ratio of police to firefighters

```
ratio_of_police = sf_sal["isPolice"].sum()
ratio_of_fire = sf_sal["isFire"].sum()
```

by using the basesalary columns, i want to sum up all the rows that have true next to the ispolice column and the same with firefighters

One way i attempted this was

```
sf_mask = sf_sal['isPolice'] == True
all_police = sf_sal[sf_mask]
sum_of_base_salary = all_police['BasePay'].sum()
print(sum_of_base_salary/ratio_of_police)
sf_mask = sf_sal['isFire'] == True
all_fire = sf_sal[sf_mask]
sum_of_base_salary = all_fire['BasePay'].sum()
print(sum_of_base_salary/ratio_of_police)
```

By looking at the comments another way would've been to use groupby statements

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
is_police_or_fire = df['JobTitle'].str.extract(r'(FIRE|POLICE)', expand=False)
out = df.groupby(is_police_or_fire)['BasePay'].mean()
```

Comment: quick question following your suggestion for example once you do, if you followed that with the drop command would it drop those rows
                                                                                                          
df.groupby(is_police_or_fire)

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to drop all rows in is_police_or_fire?

Comment: Yeah say for example if i wanted to do that instead can i follow that group by statement with a drop statement?

Comment: No, you don't. IIUC, you should do something like `df.drop(df[is_police_or_fire.notna()].index)` or better `df[is_police_or_fire.isna()]`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation.

Comment: I've had a look at groupby and it confused me so much, can you give a basic example, what i did try instead was creating a mask then making a new dataframe, then since that new dataframe only contains true, i can then sum the base_salary column